# Why would this code remove the review tab?

Tags: magento-2.1

I wanted to add an extra attribute on my product page and ran into some issues- [How to add an attribute to product page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194655/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-product-page)

The attribute is now working correctly but a few strange things happened. The review tab is now missing, the scripts for the related products slider are gone, and the css for the related products is now gone.

Here is the layout file-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
</head>
<update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
<update handle="page_calendar"/>
<body>
    <attribute name="itemtype" value="http://schema.org/Product" />
    <attribute name="itemscope" value="itemscope"/>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Catalog::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
            <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
            <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
                <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                    <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.alternatepartnumber" template="product/view/AlternatePart.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getAlternatePartNumber</argument>
                            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number</argument>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number </argument>
                            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number </argument>
                            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="alternate_part_number"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.sku">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                    <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                    <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links" after="product.info.overview">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="product/view/addto.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" />
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
        </container>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons.additional"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

This is the block I added-

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.alternatepartnumber" template="product/view/AlternatePart.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getAlternatePartNumber</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number </argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number </argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="alternate_part_number"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

Here is the template-

```
 <?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

 if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
 $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)-
 >getFrontendLabel();
 }
 $_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)-
 >getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
 ?>
 <?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
 <div class="product attibute <?php echo $_className?>">
 <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php echo 
 $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
 <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo 
 $_attributeValue; ?></div>
 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

What in here would make that disappear? This is what I was using- http://www.mohannatarajan.com/magento/magento2-get-product-attribute-value

Edit: It has worked fine but I did need to add some additional tabs to the product page. I added-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="tab.tab1" template="Documents_Tab::extra_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Documents</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="tab.tab2" template="Documents_Tab::extra_tabs.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Additional Info</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <move element="tab.tab1" destination="product.info.details" before="product.info.description" />
</body>
```

It is from this tutorial- https://magenticians.com/add-custom-tab-magento-2/

The tabs this created are still there, but the styling is gone.

Comment: where you want to show that new attribute?

Comment: I am trying to add it right next to the sku.

Comment: Please check my updated answer to move your block after SKU

Comment: Which file does the new code go in?

Comment: updated everything in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please add your block at the end of `product.info.main`. Please check last few lines

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.alternatepartnumber" template="product/view/AlternatePart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getAlternatePartNumber</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number </argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">alternate_part_number </argument>
                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="alternate_part_number"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>

  <move element="product.info.alternatepartnumber" destination="product.info.stock.sku" after="product.info.sku"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It just moved the Alternate Part Number to above the tabs, but didn't fix the missing tab or scripts.

Comment: Try Static:content:deploy, clear cache and then check it

Comment: The added the code and the attribute is displaying correctly. The problems are still there with the review tab and related products.

Comment: if you remove this code.. The problem will be resolved? Are you sure its not coming from any other 3rd party module?

Comment: If I remove this code everything works great again. I feel like there is an extra div in the phtml file but can't locate it.